# Is it acceptable scheduling a new background process task after one completes in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, background-process

I am executing the background process for my app. During my research, I understood that there would be no guarantee it would execute (based on the system mode, like battery saver, memory management, etc..). But if it is executing, can I schedule a new background process inside the task completion? Is it a bad practice? I have followed this article [article link](https://uynguyen.github.io/2020/09/26/Best-practice-iOS-background-processing-Background-App-Refresh-Task/) for to achieve that. During my testing, the background processing task was executed twice in 3 hours. However, my lead is not allowing me to schedule new background processing after the task is completed. Does iOS allow us to schedule a new background process after one another?
Also if I give `task.setTaskCompleted(success: false)` , will the background process initiate again without scheduling a new background process?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

`BGAppRefreshTask` and `BGProcessingTask` are *one shots*, that is they only fire once per schedule request.

If you want to run the task again you need to schedule it again, regardless of whether you report `true` or `false` to [`setTaskCompleted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtask/settaskcompleted(success:)):

> You can reschedule an unsuccessful required task

It is valid to schedule the next execution of your task at the completion of the background task, or you can schedule it at some other point (say, the next time your app comes to the foreground).

You can only have one pending schedule for a given task identifier, and if you request a new schedule while one is pending, then the pending request is replaced.  Therefore, scheduling the next task at the completion of the current task can be a neat way of handling it.